# Not being able to get a single object by using primary key in method FindById()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've got a table tbl_user, I'm trying to get a single object while I'm giving id from path variable. But it's giving an error in service portion whenever I'm trying to create a method by findById().

table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `contact` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` ENUM('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `contact` (`contact`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public JsonNode getUser(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable(value = "id") long userId) throws IOException {

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();

        User user = new User();

        try {
            user = userService.getUserByUserId(userId);

            if (user != null) {
                response = utility.createResponseObject(200, KeyWord.SUCCESS, new JSONObject(utility.convertPOJOtoString(user)));
            } else {
                response = utility.createResponseObject(500, KeyWord.ERROR, new JSONObject());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return objectMapper.readTree(utility.createResponse(500, KeyWord.ERROR, e.toString()).toString());
        }

        return objectMapper.readTree(response.toString());
    }
```

Service

```
public User getUserByUserId(long userId) {
        return userRepository.findById(userId);
    }
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

I'm getting red underlined over

```
public User getUserByUserId(long userId) {
        return userRepository.findById(userId);
    }
```

here.
what am i doing wrong? would be great if you could help.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `findById` definition on the `Repository` interface it returns an Optional not an entity class:

> `Optional<T> findById(ID id)`
>
> **Returns**: the entity with the given id or Optional#empty() if none
> found

Comment: @SubhaBhowmik `findOne()` does not accept an ID if you use Spring boot 2.x. You should use `findById(..)` and do something with the `Optional`. A possible (but bad) solution would be to use `repository.findById(..).orElse(null)`.